# Element animation time didn't load/start as expected using CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, footer

I want to make a pop-up footer from elements that appeared when the user hover on a small part of it using only CSS. I run the code on jsfiddle and it's working.

Unfortunately, when I run it from localhost on google version 88.0.4 (using visual studio code), I can clearly see that the element properties didn't load on time. they are generating too slow. The transition is indeed working, the problem only happened just after the refresh/the page loaded.

This is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/hzvgcw58/4/

And this is the video:
https://youtu.be/hiNX-e9uHWA

the problem occurred at 00:02 to 00:06, when I refresh the page

How to fix this?

```css
.tab-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 870px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 247, 234, 0.95);

}


.tab {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -153px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 182px;
  z-index: 9;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background-color: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}

.tab::after {
      width: 870px;
      height: 113px;
      background-color: none;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -112px;
      left: 0px;
      content: '';
      z-index: 3;
}


.a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 150px;
  height: 19px;
  background-color: rgba(54, 52, 49, 1);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}

.b {
  background-color: rgba(54, 52, 49, 1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -113px;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  height: 101px;
  width: 870px;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab:hover {
  bottom: -40px;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}

.tab:hover + .a {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  bottom: 112px;
  display: block;
}

.tab:hover ~ .b {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="footer-container">
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="tab-container">
          <div class="tab">
          </div>  
          <div class="a">
              London
          </div>
          <div class="b">
              <h3>London</h3>
              <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Thanks to @rauberdaniel the code has finally been fixed. i deleted some of unnecessary attributes such as `transition: 2s ease-in-out;` & `display: block;` in `.tab:hover + .a {` and changed a few codes in html

Answer (score 0):

Change your `transition` attributes to include only the value you want to transition (in this case `bottom`), so for example:

```css
.tab:hover {
  transition: bottom 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Be aware though that transitioning positional values like `top` or `bottom` is generally a bad idea because it will trigger a lot of expensive layout tasks for the browser. Instead, you should use `transform: translate(…)` in order to move the footer up.

Comment: Thank you so much! deleting unnecessary attributes really works!